# Wait for Button to be pressed after selecting Radiobutton then run command (Tkinter)

Tags: python, button, tkinter, radio-button

I am working on a program that uses Radiobuttons. Essentially I have 3 radiobuttons each with different options and an actual button below them. Currently if I select one of those radiobuttons it instantly runs the command which it was told to. But how would I run that command only after the main button is pressed, as kind of an "Are you sure?". I wrote some code as an example:

```
from tkinter import*

def one():
    print("one")

def two():
    print("two")

def three():
    print("three")

root = tk()
root.title("test")
root.geometry(750x650)

mainbutton = Button(root, text="Sign up to Meme Delivery" width=20, height=3).place(x=215, y=500)

check1 = Radiobutton(root, value = 1, command=one, text="Option 1 " ).place(x=215, y=300)
check2 = Radiobutton(root, value = 2, command=two, text="Option 2").place(x=215, y=340)
check3 = Radiobutton(root, value = 3, command=three, text="Option 3").place(x=215, y=380)

root.mainloop()
```

So to use this as an example if I select a radiobutton it prints what ever number it corresponds to. But how would I make it so it only prints it after the radiobutton is selected AND the main button is pressed?

Comment: If you don't want to run a command when the radiobutton is selected, why are you associating a command with the radiobutton?

Comment: It was just as an example, I didn't really know what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `variable` attribute of `RadioButton`, which sets that variable to the *value* of the corresponding radio button. Here is an example.

```
from tkinter import *

def optionselected():
    value = check.get()
    if value == 1:
        print("one")
    elif value == 2:
        print("two")
    elif value == 3:
        print("three")


root = Tk()
root.title("test")

check = IntVar()

Button(root, text="Sign up to Meme Delivery", width=20, height=3, command=optionselected).grid(row=3)

Radiobutton(root, value = 1, variable=check, text="Option 1").grid(row=0)
Radiobutton(root, value = 2, variable=check, text="Option 2").grid(row=1)
Radiobutton(root, value = 3, variable=check, text="Option 3").grid(row=2)
root.mainloop()
```